# Pandas : Get excel data based on column name and data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas for reading an excel image file which is attached below.

[file.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZNpC.png)

```
import pandas as pd
file = "file.xls"
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse("Sheet1")
```

As per excel file , I want to print what 'john' sells in other words  I want to  pass Col Name 'Seller' ,  value 'John'  , Col Names 'fruits' & 'vegetables'. O/p should be 
banana , mango , Potato & Pea.

'John' is in both Col 'Seller' & 'purchaser' , So I want to mention Col Name . 
Is it possible to fetch partial data in pandas like this or  so I need to get it based on index of value ('John' here ) from  each desired column.

Comment: You need to show us what does the `input` in the excel sheet exactly looks like, and what `output` do you expect. It helps with the thought process. You can either print the images of `input and output` or type the data on the forum using `backquote` or type `4 spaces` before putting the `input and/or output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide multiple masks here to solve this problem

```
mask1 = df['Seller'] == 'John'
mask2 = df['Buyer'] == 'John'

john = df[mask1 | mask2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select columns by boolean mask:

```
print (df['Seller'] == 'John')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: Seller, dtype: bool

df1 = df.loc[df['Seller'] == 'John', ['fruit','vegetables']]
print (df1)
   fruit vegetables
3  mango        Pea
```

If need compare by [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) case values:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Seller'].str.lower() == 'john', ['fruit','vegetables']]
print (df1)
    fruit vegetables
0  banana     Potato
3   mango        Pea
```

Also if need return all columns simply remove `loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Seller'].str.lower() == 'john']
print (df1)
  Seller   fruit vegetables purchaser
0   john  banana     Potato     Trump
3   John   mango        Pea      Mark
```

Comment: I think it will work if I use pandas.read_csv('file.csv') . I am using pandas.ExcelFile('file.xlsx').

Comment: I think you need [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)